# USB Host port disabled when Android screen is locked

Tags: android, usb

I am developing an application that communicates with an Embedded Device via the Android Devices USB Host port. I noticed that when the screen is locked USB Host port is disabled and no communication occurs.

How can I prevent the USB Host port from turning off so that communication can occur when the screen is locked?

```
-------------   USB Host            ---------------
|  Android  |  <------------------> |   Device    |
-------------                       ---------------
```

*Note: I can have root access on the Android system if necessary.*

Comment: Are you sure it is tied to the screen on/off and not the wake state?  You may want to look at a wakelock or similar.

Comment: Can the screen be locked with the wake state left on?

Comment: I believe wakelocks come in various flavors of what they preserve, so you should be able to get one which keeps the CPU awake while letting the screen turn off.  But we don't know yet that is the issue.  How soon after the screen goes off does the USB fail?

Comment: I believe `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` (*Wake lock level: Ensures that the CPU is running; the screen and keyboard backlight will be allowed to go off.*) is what I'm looking. I'll give this a try. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: For example, plugging a mouse into the USB Host port will turn the mouse off within 1 second of the screen locking.

Comment: Yup `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` did the trick. Thanks @ChrisStratton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip Chris Stratton. Using a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` the screen can turn off yet the CPU remains running. This is suitable for my application.

I created a quick app to test this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    PowerManager pm;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (wl != null) {
            wl.acquire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (wl != null) {
            wl.release();
        }
    }
```

I tested it by connecting a mouse to the USB Host. When the screen was locked the mouse did not turn off as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I came across which I have not tried. You may be able to adjust the system resource which controls the power management of the USB device. You probably need root access for this.

```
    Changing the default idle-delay time
    ------------------------------------
The default autosuspend idle-delay time (in seconds) is controlled by
a module parameter in usbcore.  You can specify the value when usbcore
is loaded.  For example, to set it to 5 seconds instead of 2 you would
do:

    modprobe usbcore autosuspend=5

Equivalently, you could add to a configuration file in /etc/modprobe.d
a line saying:

    options usbcore autosuspend=5

Some distributions load the usbcore module very early during the boot
process, by means of a program or script running from an initramfs
image.  To alter the parameter value you would have to rebuild that
image.

If usbcore is compiled into the kernel rather than built as a loadable
module, you can add

    usbcore.autosuspend=5

to the kernel's boot command line.

Finally, the parameter value can be changed while the system is
running.  If you do:

    echo 5 >/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend

then each new USB device will have its autosuspend idle-delay
initialized to 5.  (The idle-delay values for already existing devices
will not be affected.)

Setting the initial default idle-delay to -1 will prevent any
autosuspend of any USB device.  This has the benefit of allowing you
then to enable autosuspend for selected devices.
```

Source:
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.10/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt